# Unable to create new field on Activity object

Tags: custom-field, tasks, activity

I have tried to create a new field in a full copy sandbox. Where I'm getting the following error.

*Unable to Access Page
The value of a parameter contains a character that is not allowed or the value exceeds the maximum allowed length. Remove the character from the parameter value or reduce the value length and resubmit. If the error still persists, report it to our Customer Support team. Provide the URL of the page you were requesting as well as any other related information.*

When I tried to create from schema builder, getting following error

*common.exception.SfdcSqlException: ORA-20177: ORA-06512: at "HAPPY.CCUSTOMFIELDAVAILABILITY", line 660 ORA-06512: at "HAPPY.CCUSTOMFIELDCREATE", line 126 ORA-06512: at "HAPPY.CCUSTOMFIELDINSERT", line 276 ORA-06512: at "HAPPY.CCUSTOMFIELDDEFINITION", line 326 ORA-06512: at line 1 {call cCustomFieldDefinition.bulk_insert_detail(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)} {call cCustomFieldDefinition.bulk_insert_detail(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}*

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue fixed after raising ticket with SF. As per them, sometimes this issue occurs when there are many processes happening at that moment. They fixed this from their side later it started working normal.
Thanks for your quick response @Dan!

Answer (score 0):

The internal Salesforce servers were named after the 7 dwarfs from Snow White. That's an oracle error that Salesforce will need to fix. I'd log a ticket with them.

However, to get around it it's probably how you named the field. Did your field have weird characters in it? Or the name really long?

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
I don't have any special characters in my field name. Even I have tried to create a field with name as "test"

Comment: Very strange, try SF support, now I'm curious as to what's happening.